# How to capture a variable in groovy append function?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am writing a Gradle task to define a Global Artifact Marker for my executable being generated. This task will create a `C` file which will later be packaged into the executable containing other sources.

```
task genArtifactMarker{
        project.ext.HASH = "git rev-parse --short HEAD".execute().text
        project.ext.ARTIFACT_VERSION = "$PROJECT-$VERSION-$HASH"
        def version_file = new File('version.c')
        version_file.append('\n/* Automatically generated file for marker */')
        version_file.append('\nconst volatile char marker[] __attribute__ ((section ("MARKER"))) = "${ARTIFACT_VERSION}";')
}
```

How do I capture the `ARTIFACT_VERSION` variable within the append function? I want something like `MY_EXE-V2.1.2-47add78`in the place of `ARTIFACT_VERSION` in my generated `version.c` file.

**EDIT:**

Adding code to help request for debugging.

```
task genArtifactMarker{
    doLast{
        project.ext.HASH = "git rev-parse --short HEAD".execute().text
        def ARTIFACT_VERSION = "$PROJECT-$VERSION-$HASH"
        def version_file = new File('version.c')
        version_file.append('\n/* Automatically generated file for marker */')
        version_file << """\nconst volatile char marker[] __attribute__ ((section ("MARKER"))) = "${ARTIFACT_VERSION}";"""
    }
}
```

My output is as follows:

```
/* Automatically generated file for marker */ 
const volatile char marker[] __attribute__ ((section ("MARKER"))) = "RPI-V2.1.2_PO3-e75ee8d 
";
```

I want my output as below:

```
/* Automatically generated file for marker */ 
const volatile char marker[] __attribute__ ((section ("MARKER"))) = "RPI-V2.1.2_PO3-e75ee8d";
```

Comment: You are doing the "work" in gradle's configuration phase when it should be done in the execution phase. Wrap your logic in a `doLast { ... }` closure

Comment: Point noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coalescing the above answers and adding the [`<<` append operator](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_writing_files) for files and [triple double quoted strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string) in groovy we get:

```
ext { 
  version_file = file('text.txt')
  ARTIFACT_VERSION ="1.0"
}

task genArtifactMarker {
  doLast { 
    version_file << """\nconst volatile char marker[] __attribute__ ((section ("MARKER"))) = "${ARTIFACT_VERSION}";"""
  }
}
```

or if you need to control the indentation level of a multi line string:

```
task genArtifactMarker {
  doLast { 
    version_file << """
     |const volatile char marker[] __attribute__ ((section ("MARKER"))) = "${ARTIFACT_VERSION}";
     |
     |more text needing correct indentation
     |""".stripMargin()
  }
}
```

As we are using the `doLast` block, we are now executing the code in the execution phase in gradle and since we are using triple quotes, we don't need to escape the quotes with backslash characters inside the string.

The groovy [stripMargin()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#stripMargin()) method can be used to get a multi-line string nicely aligned in your code without affecting the formatting of the resulting string.

edit: in response to comment, here is the output of the last version of the code:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 mbjarland mbjarland 628 Feb  7 15:08 build.gradle

$ gradle genArtifactMarker
:genArtifactMarker

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.102 secs

$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 mbjarland mbjarland 628 Feb  7 15:08 build.gradle
-rw-r--r-- 1 mbjarland mbjarland 115 Feb  8 15:26 text.txt

$ cat text.txt 

const volatile char marker[] __attribute__ ((section ("MARKER"))) = "1.0";

more text needing correct indentation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I still cannot get the `";` on the same line as the C statement. I have copy pasted both versions of your code. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I have updated my question with the latest code.

Comment: added an edit with the output I get when executing the task. It really should stick the `"` and `;` on the same line.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with the output of the git command. My git rev-parse came with plenty of trailing white spaces. So, I did a `project.ext.HASH = "git rev-parse --short HEAD".execute().text.replaceAll("\\s","")` to get rid of it. Now I have everything on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quotes to get templating:

```
version_file.append("\nconst volatile char marker[] __attribute__ ((section (\"MARKER\"))) = \"${ARTIFACT_VERSION}\";")
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I get the final `";` (closing double quotes and semi-colon on a new line). Also, what is exactly the significance of \ backslashes?